# Add more buildings to Simcity3000

Tags: mods, simcity-3000

I got a bunch of *bld* files to add new buildings to Simcity3000 unlimited.

But whne i try to import them, i can only swap one existing building for one of the new ones, so the total number of buildings in game remains the same.

Is it possible to ADD new buildings without losing the vainilla ones?